# Django HTML5 -- downloading a file

Tags: python, django, upload

This is my .html file. It enables the user to upload files and see the list of files uploaded, and download the files on the list -- or is supposed to!

The problem is that `document.docfile.url` (`docfile` is the `FileField` object) doesn't return the desired file path. The desired filepath contains `'media'` but the returned file path is myapp/list/(...)

My `MEDIA_URL` is `'media'`, that is.

I suspect this is an inadequate explanation, so just let me know if you need further information.

```
<body>
    <!-- List of uploaded documents -->
    {% if documents %}
        <ul>
        {% for document in documents %}
            <li><a href="{{ document.docfile.url }}">{{ document.docfile.name }}</a> 
            <a href="{{ document.docfile.url }}" download="document.docfile.url">Download</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% else %}
        <p>No documents.</p>
    {% endif %}

    <!-- Upload form. Note enctype attribute! -->
    <form action="{% url "list" %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p>{{ form.non_field_errors }}</p>
        <p>{{ form.docfile.label_tag }} {{ form.docfile.help_text }}</p>
        <p>
            {{ form.docfile.errors }}
            {{ form.docfile }}
        </p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></p>
    </form>

</body>
```

This is my `views.py:`

```
def list(request):
    # Handle file upload
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newdoc = Document(docfile = request.FILES['docfile'])
            newdoc.save()

            # Redirect to the document list after POST
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('myapp.views.list'))
    else:
        form = DocumentForm() # An empty, unbound form

    # Load documents for the list page
    documents = Document.objects.all()

    # Render list page with the documents and the form
    return render_to_response(
        'myapp/list.html',
        {'documents': documents, 'form': form},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    )
```

Comment: there's an error at '<a href="{{ document.docfile.url }}" download="document.docfile.url">Download</a></li>' in the download attribute

Comment: Are you sure? I think the problem is that document.docfile.url doesn't return what I want it to return.

Comment: download="document.docfile.url" should be download="{{ document.docfile.url }}"... can you please post your MEDIA_ROOT settings? MEDIA_URL should be in slashes '/media/' if i remember correctly

Comment: MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media') where BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

Comment: I suspect the error lies in here

urlpatterns = patterns('',
 (r'^myapp/', include('myapp.urls')),
 (r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/myapp/list/')), # Just for ease of use.
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

This is my application's urls.py.

Comment: I'm so embarrassed. I had, by accident, commented MEDIA_URL. LOL

Post your answer, I'll mark it as correct. Since you told me that.. uh.. MEDIA_URL is not supposed to be commented.

Comment: very nice... good luck